# Find instead of see word

Tags: grammar

Can you replace see by find word as finding someone attractive or something like that?

What did you find in this guy?

Comment: You could ask, "How how did you find him?" or "Did you find him attractive?" But "What did you find in this guy" is a bit weird, as Kevin says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  "What did you find in this guy?" sounds like you're asking for the results of an autopsy